# Rearrange XML siblings using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSLT to transform a XML document into a new XML document with more meaning.
Source XML:

```
<root>
  <A>
    <country>Italy</country>
    <city>Rome</city>
    <score>13</score>
  </A>
  <A>
    <country>Italy</country>
    <city>Florence</city>
    <score>14</score>
  </A>
  <A>
    <country>France</country>
    <city>Paris</city>
    <score>20</score>
  </A>
</root>
```

The nodes `<country>`, `<city>` and `<score>` are all siblings.
My question is: How can I rearrange the siblings like this in XSLT?

```
<country>
  <city>
    <score>
    </score>
  </city>
</country>
```

My expected XML:

```
<root>
  <Italy>
    <Rome>
      <score>13</score>
    </Rome>
    <Florence>
      <score>14</score>
    </Florence>
  </Italy>
  <France>
    <Paris>
      <score>20</score>
    </Paris>
  </France>
</root>
```

Comment: Can you use XSLT-2.0?

Comment: @zx485 Yes. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XSLT-1.0 solution is the following. It uses [*Muenchian Grouping*](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) as a method to get unique country values.

**EDIT:**
To ensure that the element names are valid QNames, I added a `translate(...)` expression which transforms all spaces in the respective city name or country name to underscores.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="countries" match="A" use="country" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />    

    <xsl:template match="A[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('countries',country)[1])]">
        <xsl:element name="{translate(country,' ','_')}">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('countries',country)">
                <xsl:element name="{translate(city,' ','_')}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="score" />
                </xsl:element>           
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

The XSLT-2.0 solution is easier, because it can use `xsl:for-each-group`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="A" group-by="country">
                <xsl:element name="{translate(current-grouping-key(),' ','_')}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:element name="{translate(city,' ','_')}">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="score" />
                        </xsl:element>           
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**The output of both approaches is the same:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <Italy>
        <Rome>
            <score>13</score>
        </Rome>
        <Florence>
            <score>14</score>
        </Florence>
    </Italy>
    <France>
        <Paris>
            <score>20</score>
        </Paris>
    </France>
</root>
```

Comment: Instead of `current-group()[1]/country` you could use `current-grouping-key()`.

Comment: It might also be worth adding a comment about how trying to create an element name from a country like "United States of America" will result in an invalid QName error (same goes for city values that are not valid QNames). Hopefully the requested output was just a simple example and the OP really isn't trying to create element names based on country/city.

Comment: @DanielHaley: Thanks for your suggestions. I added a (parital) solution for the QName issue.